# Vertically misaligned text in a split rectangle

Tags: tikz-pgf

The following `tikz`-code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.multipart}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
[my shape/.style={
rectangle split, rectangle split parts=#1, draw, anchor=center, text
height=4mm, text width=16mm}]

\node [my shape=4, rectangle split horizontal, rectangle split part fill={red!50, green!50}] at (2,2)
{px\nodepart{two}py\nodepart{three}pz\nodepart{four}pw};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Results in the following image:

[image]

As can be seen, for some reason "px" is positioned lower than "py", "pz", and "pw". How can I fix this?

Also, I wish to center the four strings within their boxes. What would
be the best way of doing this?

Answer (score 2):

The text inside the parts can be aligned by option `rectangle split part align`. The text is horizontally centered by option `align=center`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.multipart}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[
    my shape/.style={
      rectangle split,
      rectangle split parts=#1,
      rectangle split part align=base,
      align=center,
      draw,
      anchor=center,
      text height=4mm,
      text width=16mm
    },
  ]
    \node [
      my shape=4,
      rectangle split horizontal,
      rectangle split part fill={red!50, green!50}
    ] at (2,2)
    {px\nodepart{two}py\nodepart{three}pz\nodepart{four}pw};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

The place above and below the base line can be influenced by `text height` and `text depth`. Here a smaller value for `text height` would look better, e.g.:

```
text height=height("A")
```

> [image: Result with smaller text height]